# Connected Bluetooth Speaker not playing sound

Tags: raspbian, audio, bluetooth

I have connected my Bluetooth speakers to my Raspberry Pi (Wheezy). But my problem is, that the Pi is not recognizing the bluetooth speakers. There is no sound, but the player plays my music.
If i connect the speakers to my mobile phone everything works fine.

So can anybody tell me where and how to configure my audio output so that my speakers are working with my Raspberry? I'm using pulseaudio

Comment: This is very late to the game, but what version are you using? There was a version of pulseaudio that did not have bluetooth enabled. Check the config files for pulseaudio and ensure that BT is configured.

Comment: I made a step by step guide for alsa that might be an option for you after all https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90267/how-to-stream-sound-to-a-bluetooth-device-from-a-raspberry-pi-zero