# How to stream sound to a bluetooth device from a raspberry pi zero

Tags: bluetooth, alsa, bluez

I have a raspberry pi zero W and I would like to stream sound over bluetooth to a bluetooth-enabled speaker / headphone.

So how to achieve this with `alsa`?

Comment: see [this link](https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/bluetooth_n_buster_01_en.html), there are some more details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did manage to play sound and record using my Marshall MID headphones using a Raspberry Pi Zero W, which has a builtin WiFi + Bluetooth adapter, but no audio jack.

Please note that there are different approaches using different tools such as `bluez` `alsa` and `pulseaudio`, `hcitool`, `bluetoothctl`.

#### Install bluez-alsa

[Bluez Alsa](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa) let's you play sound on a bluetooth speaker like so:

```
aplay -D bluealsa:DEV=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF,PROFILE=a2dp,HCI=hci0 ~/piano.wav
```

You'll have to install the `bluealsa` client from source.

```
cd && git clone https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa.git
cd bluez-alsa
# git checkout tags/v1.3.1 -b v1.3.1
sudo apt install bluez bluez-tools -y
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev -y
sudo apt install libasound2-dev -y
sudo apt install build-essential autoconf -y
sudo apt install libbluetooth-dev -y
sudo apt install libtool -y
sudo apt install libsbc-dev -y
# sudo apt install libbsd-dev libfdk-aac-dev libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev -y

mkdir -p m4
autoreconf --install
mkdir build && cd build
# ../configure --enable-aac --enable-debug
#../configure --enable-debug
../configure CFLAGS="-g -O0" LDFLAGS="-g" --enable-debug
make && sudo make install
```

Now you can run `sudo bluealsa -S` in a seperate terminal. You can startup `bluealsa` by it to `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit` line:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Now add

```
# Start bluealsa as root <https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa>
export LIBASOUND_THREAD_SAFE=0
/usr/bin/bluealsa -S &
```

Reboot and make sure that it's running: `ps -ef | grep bluealsa`

#### User groups

Add the pi user to the audio and the bluetooth group

```
sudo adduser pi bluetooth
sudo adduser pi audio
```

#### `bluetoothd` with a2dp plugin

There is a `a2dp` plugin for our bluetooth agent. So we'll change the services' `ExecStart` parameter like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service
```

And while we're here we'll disable `sap` since this may cause [some errors](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=131999#p932442):

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap --plugin=a2dp
```

Now reload and restart the agent:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart bluetooth
```

#### bluetoothctl

I run `bluetoothctl` and issue the following commands:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
list
# Controller XXXXXX mydevice [default]
power on
agent on
default-agent
scan on
# [NEW] Device AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF XYZ
# Now I Press the pairing button on the device (disabling bluetooth on any nearby devices)
connect AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
trust AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
exit
```

The `trust` command will enable to auto-pair the device again later on.

If auto-connecting does not work after reboot you may add the following line to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo -e "power up\nconnect AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF\n quit"|bluetoothctl
```

#### Alsa config

Now let's create a config for our bluetooth device and add it either to `/etc/asound.conf` (global) or `~/.asoundrc` (per-user basis).

```
    pcm.mid {
        type plug
        slave {
            pcm {
                type bluealsa
                device AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
                profile "a2dp"
            }
        }
        hint {
            show on
            description "Marshall MID"
        }
     }
```

#### Playback and recording

Now that the devices is connected you should be able to playback like so:

```
aplay -D mid ~/piano.wav
```

Alternatively you can specify the address and profile like so:

```
aplay -D bluealsa:DEV=2C:4D:79:0D:17:F9,PROFILE=a2dp,HCI=hci0 ~/piano.wav
```

For recording you'll need a different profile:

```
arecord -D bluealsa:DEV=2C:4D:79:0D:17:F9,PROFILE=sco ~/test.wav
```

This may result in poor sound quality.

## Troubleshooting

There are a few things that can go wrong so here some troubleshooting pointers.

#### Bluetoothctl

- `list` lists the interfaces. Use `select XX:XX:XX...` to select another interface
- `devices` list the devices. Use `scan on`, `scan off` to find new devices.
- `info XX:XX:XX...` show information about the given device
- `remove XX:XX:XX...` to remove a pairing and connection use remove. This can be helpful for starting over, when there are problems with the pairing process.

#### Unpair from other devices

Often the bluetooth devices may be connected to other computers, smartphones tablets. These devices can block a new pairing so make sure to switch those devices off or remove the pairing.

#### Bad file descriptor

I encountered an error when starting `bluealsa` which was :

> bluealsa: Couldn't initialize controller thread: Bad file descriptor

In this case I had to delete the `hci*` file in the `/run` directory:

```
sudo rm /run/bluealsa/hci*
```

I would also get this message when running `bluealsa` without `sudo`.

#### Bluetooth service

You can get some logs by running

```
journalctl | grep blue
```

The status of the bluetooth service will also show some possible errors (Such as the `SAP` server error from above):

```
GFP> service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-10-24 08:59:08 UTC; 4s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 566 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─566 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Oct 24 08:59:08 godfatherphone systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Oct 24 08:59:08 godfatherphone systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Oct 24 08:59:08 godfatherphone bluetoothd[566]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
Oct 24 08:59:08 godfatherphone systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Oct 24 08:59:08 godfatherphone bluetoothd[566]: Starting SDP server
Oct 24 08:59:09 godfatherphone bluetoothd[566]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Oct 24 08:59:09 godfatherphone bluetoothd[566]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Oct 24 08:59:09 godfatherphone bluetoothd[566]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Oct 24 08:59:09 godfatherphone bluetoothd[566]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Oct 24 08:59:09 godfatherphone bluetoothd[566]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.6 path=/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
```

The following lines are in red:

- Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
- Sap driver initialization failed.
- sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)

## Information and debugging

#### Additional packages

```
sudo apt install blueman xauth -y
sudo apt install -y obex-data-server
```

#### Logfiles

Logs to check during debugging

```
dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
tail -f /var/log/syslog
journalctl -u bluetooth
```

#### No such device

At some point I got the following error message:

```
ALSA lib ../../../src/asound/bluealsa-pcm.c:666:(_snd_pcm_bluealsa_open) Couldn't get BlueALSA transport: No such device
aplay: main:788: audio open error: No such device
```

This message won't come if the device is connected and paired.

#### Displaying the connected devices:

```
 $ busctl tree org.bluez
└─/org
  └─/org/bluez
    └─/org/bluez/hci0
      ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_79_0D_17_F9
      └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_26_AF_79_03
```

#### Status of bluetooth

The System D status command will give you the status and errors of the bluetooth agent.

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth


● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-10-24 18:21:16 UTC; 14min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 615 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─615 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap

Oct 24 18:21:16 mypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Oct 24 18:21:16 mypi bluetoothd[615]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
Oct 24 18:21:16 mypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Oct 24 18:21:16 mypi bluetoothd[615]: Starting SDP server
Oct 24 18:21:16 mypi bluetoothd[615]: Excluding (cli) sap
Oct 24 18:21:16 mypi bluetoothd[615]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Oct 24 18:21:16 mypi bluetoothd[615]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Oct 24 18:23:29 mypi bluetoothd[615]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.12 path=/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Oct 24 18:23:29 mypi bluetoothd[615]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.12 path=/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Oct 24 18:23:43 mypi bluetoothd[615]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.13 path=/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
```

#### Policy User

According to [wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Headset_via_Bluez5.2Fbluez-alsa):

> Edit the file `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf` and add these lines to the bottom, just before the closing `</busconfig>`.
>
> ```
> <policy user="bluealsa">
>   <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
> </policy>
> ```

#### Optional: Get the address of the the bluetooth device

On my mac I hit `⌥` while pressing the bluetooth icon in the status bar.

[image]

Comment: mp3 does not work, only wav ...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was able to stream a mp3 file to connected BT speaker. However, what I am trying to achieve is to route all the sound playback over to BT device. So, the default audio sink should be set to connected BT speaker. Can you give me a pointer in that direction?

Comment: omg, THANK YOU! I've tried soooooo many tutorials, guides, tips etc and this was the only solution that actually works for my headless Pi Zero W.
I have working bluetooth audio now! Yay!

Comment: @HankScorpio I'm very glad you're able to listen to some wireless music now =)

Answer (score 0):

Note: When setting up /etc/asound.conf or .asoundrc if you set it as "default" then you don't need to specify the device when calling aplay. ie:

```
aplay ~/piano.wav
```

instead of

```
aplay -D mid ~/piano.wav
```

To do this the asoundrc should appear like so

```
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave.pcm {
                type bluealsa
                device "MAC address"
                profile "a2dp"
        }
}
ctl.!default {
type bluealsa
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting of the asoundrc file. I cannot seem to find a way to post this with all the nice formatting included but you can add the format as you like when adding the text to your asoundrc file. Note: This default works for the mplayer example used above as well.

Comment: Re formatting: indent with 4 spaces or use 'code' button in the editor